# How would I go about getting the lowest and highest coordinate numbers from touchpoints?

Tags: swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, cgrect

I'm wanting to get the lowest and highest x and y coordinates from the touchesmoved event no matter what the shape being drawn is. Basically I want to create a cgrect that encompasses the shape. I have no idea how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.

`UIBezierPath` has a bounds method that will give you a bounding rectangle that contains all the points in the path. If you are building your shape into a `UIBezierPath` that should be all you need.

If you need to track the bounds yourself, set up some variables and adjust them as needed:

```
var minY = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
var maxY = -CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude

var minX = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
var maxX = -CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
```

As you collect points from your user, if the `x` coordinate is `< minX`, update `minX`. If it's `> maxX`, update `maxX`. Do the same for `minY` and `maxY`.

Once you have maximum and minimum values for `x` and `y` it's trivial to convert those values to a bounding rectangle. Some sample code:

```
extension CGRect {
    init(minX: CGFloat,
         minY: CGFloat,
         maxX: CGFloat,
         maxY: CGFloat) {
        self.init()
       origin = CGPoint(x: minX, y: minY)
       size = CGSize(width: maxX - minX, height: maxY - minY)
   }
}


let aMinX: CGFloat = CGFloat(Int.random(in: 0...50))
let aMinY: CGFloat = CGFloat(Int.random(in: 0...50))
let aMaxX: CGFloat = CGFloat(Int.random(in: 60...200))
let aMaxY: CGFloat = CGFloat(Int.random(in: 60...200))
let aRect: CGRect = CGRect(minX: aMinX,
                           minY: aMinY,
                           maxX: aMaxX,
                           maxY: aMaxY)
print(aRect)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but something is not right. Using this code in the touchesmoved event I get a big difference each time I trace the same path. I realize using a mouse I'm not going to get exact but tracing an image 5 times gets significantly different rect sizes.(15,43,56,76) (28,9,32,55)(41,42,125,134)(5,4,10,71)(38,48,128,73) Thoughts?

Comment: I banged that code out in about 5 minutes. It's untested, and is only intended as a guide on your approach. (And I didn't provide the code that detects touches that exceed the maximums/minimums.) You'll need to test and debug it. I would suggest having your test version draw a translucent rectangle around the bounding box it comes up with so you can see what it's doing.

Comment: It looks like I used the wrong constants for starting values. You should use `greatestFiniteMagnitude` and `-greatestFiniteMagnitude` instead. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ok, I found what I needed, and thanks for your help. I ended up just using path.bounds.size(width and height)

Comment: Yup, using the bounds of the path was my first suggestion.

Comment: Just for giggles then I added the touchpoints to an array and then got the rect points like this.       let minx = points.map( {$0.x} ).min()
                    let maxx = points.map( {$0.x} ).max()
                    let miny = points.map( {$0.y} ).min()
                    let maxy = points.map( {$0.y} ).max()                                                              Thanks for the suggestions.